# Why is bootstrap not working all of a sudden?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am running bootstrap on React, and then using Storybook to view it.
This is the code that I ran on Friday, and it was working without any problems. Today, I run it, and it's no longer working! I ran it on Jsfiddle and onecompiler, and still not working. I copied the carousel component from the bootstrap website, pasted it in my vscode, ran it, and it's not working! I pasted it in jsfiddle and onecompiler, and still not working! What is happening here? Why is it not working all of a sudden? Am I doing something wrong? By 'not working' I mean clicking on the left/right indicators does not move the slider!

Here's the code that I'm running:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" className="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        <div className="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

I just copied it from bootstrap, and just replaced class with className to make it work on React, but it's not working. Everywhere is where it's supposed to be with the exception that indicators and controls do not work.

I feel like the issue has to do with me using normal bootstrap for React, rather than React Bootstrap, which does work! But normal bootstrap also worked on Friday, why is it not working now? And why is it not working in any online compiler either? Does it work for you? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the following to find a possible resolution :

1. Check if you have provided link to bootstrap in index.html or alternatively have you correctly installed bootstrap using npm.
2. Have you installed or linked to the correct version of bootstrap for which you have taken the carousel.
3. In my opinion, rule of thumb to get through the styles in frontend is to inspect the elements and the console. Try checking if bootstrap styles are applied to the divs in the inspect element styles.

Comment: I just checked by adding a bootstrap defined class, and it works! So, bootstrap itself works, but why aren't the indicators/controls working?

Comment: Have you tried checking the version of the bootstrap and the carousel ?

Comment: Also, do your carousel anchor tags have proper href pointing to your carousel id ?

Comment: How do I check the version of the carousel? My carousel doesn't have anchor tags. It's the same as the code snippet from above.

Comment: `data-bs-target` is supposed to target the ID of the container, and it is. So, why is it not working? I just played around with the sass, and I can edit the `indicators` or `controls`, but why is the sliding function not working? What could be wrong?

Comment: By carousel version, I mean from which version of bootstrap have you copy-pasted the carousel ? Check and get the carousel for the same version of bootstrap that you have.

Comment: I think this is bootstrap js bundle problem.

Comment: I copied it from the latest `5.2`

Comment: The one that I have in my dependencies is `"bootstrap": "^5.1.3"`, but that shouldn't make the carousel not work, right? Why was it working on Friday then?

Comment: I just imported the js bundle, and it worked! But how come it was working on Friday is what I don't understand..

Comment: There can be some changes or possibly, your browser can have cached bootstrap javascript somehow as you switched between versions. Please accept my answer if you found it relevant.

Comment: Where do I have to import the JS bundle so I can use it throughout my react project? I have an `index.js` file, and in it, I have `import 'bootstrap` statement, but I still can't understand what am I importing here, and from where? And if I also import the `js bundle` beneath it, it's not working. Where do I have to import the `bootstrap js bundle` so it can be available throughout the app?

Comment: You can do it in App.js file.

Comment: I can't, because the project I'm working on does not have one. We are using storybook to run the react components. Do you have any idea what does `import 'bootstrap'` import, and from where?

Comment: I believe it imports all the CSS as well as JS. You can alternatively provide link to bootstrap cdn in your index.html file.

Comment: I just imported the `index.js` from the `dist` folder only for the component I am using because I don't have a root file like `app.js`.